# Resolve relative urls of youtube using PHP

Tags: php, video, youtube

**This question is asked before but non of the answers worked for me.**

I use the following code to directly copy a file from a remote server to my server,

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0); //Unlimited max execution time
$remote_file_url = $_GET['url'];
$ext = pathinfo($remote_file_url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$name = basename($remote_file_url);
if(isset($ext)){
    $local_file = 'download/'.$name.'.'.$ext;
}
else
    $local_file = 'download/'.$name;
$copy = copy( $remote_file_url, "1.mp4" );

if( !$copy ) {
    echo "Doh! failed to copy $file...\n";
}
else{
    echo "WOOT! success to copy $file...\n";
    
}
?>
```

It works well but it doesn't copy the files I get from [Youtube](http://youtube.com). I use `1-Click Youtube Video Downloader` extension for Firefox which gives me direct link to youtube videos. I can use these direct links in browser and Internet Download Manager as well.

For example the direct url of

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPXrJwQ5lqQ

is

https://r6---sn-ab5l6nzy.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&requiressl=yes&sparams=dur,ei,expire,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,ipbypass,itag,lmt,mime,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source&ei=3DNOWfq4CImGc9rxvcgO&signature=3D188D073D872381433A45462E84928383D10D02.4E0AF7D777E76AA19A576D42983A81F4E62EF84D&lmt=1472135086539955&mime=video%2Fmp4&ratebypass=yes&id=o-ABaoUEn3pBt5SLXdWXlrzCdteMLfLPizrRTPoakDoLSX&expire=1498318908&source=youtube&dur=119.211&itag=22&pl=20&ip=162.217.31.128&key=cms1&redirect_counter=1&req_id=ce038b9993a9a3ee&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mip=159.203.89.210&mm=31&mn=sn-ab5l6nzy&ms=au&mt=1498297234&mv=m

The problem is my code can't copy this file to my server. I would like to know of there is any way to resolve such urls?

The error is

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /home/...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have no idea why that happened. (Would it be expired?I hope not) I just managed to try [another link for the above video (copy the link using right click)](https://r8---sn-5abxgpxuxaxjvh-j1ae.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?signature=8052B7F7FF3791D45080D6E747E75F4E85D931EF.4C7BB827298C72AD3575BC64AC514127653571CA&mime=video%2F3gpp&initcwndbps=86250&requiressl=yes&mt=1510414668&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cexpire&ipbits=0&ip=105.103.165.140&key=yt6&lmt=1365152704276718&source=youtube&mv=m&ms=au&mm=31&mn=sn-5abxgpxuxaxjvh-j1ae&id=o-ACldX6xCc_W5HMlr5ot6uB5r91Ex_dIE64dOwphx3zNY&dur=119.490&clen=1175010&itag=17&expire=1510436415&gir=yes&pl=16&ei=3hkHWu79NoPkcYf6hbgM&title=Lion-vs-Hyenas-Original-uncut-epic-battle) in your code as the `$remote_file_url` and it worked as expected

- How did I get that link?

I've used [the underlined library : YouTube-Downloader](https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader/)  to `the 1-Click Youtube Video Downloader extension` (it is inherently used by that extension ) this way you will have more control over the process. Then after hosting the files in your web server. Simply run the `index.php` and when you use it, you'll get something like :

[image: Running YouTube-Downloader screenshot]

Then you can automate this last part to suit your needs.

That doesn't mean that all videos could be smoothly downloaded with this method. Because of  [the used videos that have signatures issue](https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader/issues/278) or [that are recently uploaded issue](https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader/issues/273) and [here's the list of issues of Youtube-Downloader](https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader/issues/)

For that There is a fix that is somewhat involved: [youtube-dl-php](https://github.com/norkunas/youtube-dl-php), it is based on a sound principle : there is a very good command line utility to download YouTube videos called `youtube-dl` : here is [the download page](https://youtube-dl.org/)
Basically, you'll just call it using `php`. Then, notice that you'll need its path installed in order for the following to work

- After you install [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/), go to your web project folder
  and run `composer require norkunas/youtube-dl-php` as explained in the [Github page](https://github.com/norkunas/youtube-dl-php)
- When running its example, I've get an error

  > proc_open() 267 CreateProcess failed

I've never dealt with `Symphony` before and I've found it particularly interesting to play with `YoutubeDl.php` and redefine the `$arguments` passed to `createProcess` and commenting out much of the less useful configuration options to get rid of that error, give it more time to run with
`ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` 
And yikes it was downloaded. 
You don't have to follow this unless you couldn't figure out a better way. It is just supposed to give you an idea of where lies the problem if you havn'et figure it out. And if you have that problem in the first place.

```
private function createProcess(array $arguments = [])
    {
        array_unshift($arguments, $this->binPath ?: 'youtube-dl');

        $process = new Process("youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDMwW41AlSI");
        /*$process->setEnv(['LANG' => 'en_US.UTF-8']);
        $process->setTimeout($this->timeout);
        $process->setOptions($this->processOptions);

        if ($this->moveWithPhp) {
            $cwd = sys_get_temp_dir();
        } else {
            $cwd = $this->downloadPath ?: sys_get_temp_dir();
        }

        $process->setWorkingDirectory($cwd);*/

        return $process;
    }
```

Or you can just write your own code that calls `youtube-dl`, good luck!